# C# Going back to previous image in listview and displaying it in Picturebox

Tags: c#, image, listview, picturebox, imagelist

I’m trying to select the previous image in the list view and display it in the picture box on the right. I’m using _imageIndex to keep track of what’s in the picture box currently and if it’s less than the image list length then I select the image in the list view and using the _imageIndex counter to access the image.

But it’s like it’s not getting the image index at all. It just keeps reading it at 0 and decrementing it to negative 1 and return an error when I click btnPrevious again.

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'InvalidArgument=Value of '-1' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index'
```

I know I set it to _imageIndex to 0 in the mnuOpen_Click event. Other than that I don’t know how to solve this. For clarity here is an image of the [GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aubJ.jpg).  Ideas please?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string _big_fileName;
    int _counter = 0;
    int _imageIndex;

    public Form1()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //Displays larger instance of selected image in picture box.
    private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //FOR i is less than the first image.
        for (int i = 0; i < listView1.SelectedItems.Count;i++)
        {                
            //GET filename from listview and store in index.
            _big_fileName = listView1.SelectedItems[i].Text;
            //Create larger instance of image.
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(_big_fileName);
            //Fill panel to the width and height of picture box.
            panel1.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(pictureBox1.Image.Width, pictureBox1.Image.Height);
        }
    }

    private void mnuOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        loadImageList();
        _imageIndex = 0;
    }

    private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
        {                
            //IF Image is less than Image list size.
            if (_imageIndex < imageList1.Images.Count)
            {
                //SELECT  listview items with counter.
                listView1.Items[_imageIndex].Selected = true;
                //GO to previous entry.
                _imageIndex--;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No image.");
        }
    }

    //Cycle to next image in image list and display in Picturebox.
    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(pictureBox1.Image != null)
        {
            //IF Image is less than Image list size.
            if (_imageIndex < imageList1.Images.Count)
            {
                listView1.Items[_imageIndex].Selected = true;

                _imageIndex++;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No image.");
        }
    }

    private void loadImageList()
    {
        imageList1.Images.Clear();
        listView1.Clear();

        oFD1.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
        oFD1.Title = "Open an Image File";
        oFD1.Filter = "JPEGS|*.jpg|GIFS|*.gif|PNGS|*.png|BMPS|*.bmp";

        //Open Dialog Box.
        var oldResults = oFD1.ShowDialog();

        if (oldResults == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            //GET amount of filenames.
            int num_of_files = oFD1.FileNames.Length;
            //Store filenames in string array.
            string[] arryFilePaths = new string[num_of_files];


            //FOREACH filename in the file.
            foreach (string single_file in oFD1.FileNames)
            {
                //ACCESS array using _counter to find file.
                arryFilePaths[_counter] = single_file;
                //CREATE image in memory and add image to image list.
                imageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(single_file));
                _counter++;
            }
            //BIND image list to listview.
            listView1.LargeImageList = imageList1;


            for (int i = 0; i < _counter; i++)
            {
                //DISPLAY filename and image from image index param. 
                listView1.Items.Add(arryFilePaths[i], i);
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex.Message);
        }
    }      
}
```

Comment: Does your ListView allow MulitSelect?

Comment: Yes. I can see it set to true in properties.

Comment: OK. Why? Does it make any sense?? I doubt it; try to change to false and see if it helps..!

Comment: Yes I tried it with the value of false. MultiSelect was set to true by default so I didn't even know. Still I switched it to false and C# still returned the same error at runtime. But It's ok now. Problem is now solved. Thanks @Caldazar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you're not setting _imageIndex anywhere, except in btnPrevious_Click, where you set it to 0.

You need to set it to selected index, in SelectedIndexChanged method, like this (notice the last line added to your previous code):

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //FOR i is less than the first image.
        for (int i = 0; i < listView1.SelectedItems.Count; i++)
        {
            //GET filename from listview and store in index.
            _big_fileName = listView1.SelectedItems[i].Text;
            //Create larger instance of image.
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(_big_fileName);
            //Fill panel to the width and height of picture box.
            panel1.AutoScrollMinSize = new Size(pictureBox1.Image.Width, pictureBox1.Image.Height);
            _imageIndex = listView1.SelectedIndices[0];
        }
    }
```

Next, in btnPreviousClick, you need to make few changes:

```
private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
        {
            //IF Image is less than Image list size.
            if (_imageIndex >= 0 && _imageIndex < imageList1.Images.Count)
            {
                //De-select current item
                listView1.Items[_imageIndex].Selected = false;
                //GO to previous entry.
                _imageIndex--;
                //Select new item
                if(_imageIndex>=0){
                   listView1.Items[_imageIndex].Selected = true;
                   listView1.Select();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No image.");
        }
    }
```

It's necessary to call Select() method on listView1. Biggest issue was that you didn't set _imageIndex though.

Hope this is what you were looking for :)

Best regards,

Comment: 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' would occur when I was at the end of the index. Happened on this line `listView1.Items[_imageIndex].Selected = false;`
I fixed it by deleting that line.

Comment: Are you sure it's not after decreasing of _imageIndex? That would make sense, since _imageIndex could go below zero. Just added a check for that.

Comment: _imageIndex won't decrease if I've selected the last item of listview1. So the Autos window shows that  _imageIndex have the same value as listView1 so it won't execute the 2nd IF statement.

Comment: @JordanNash did you somewhere before that increase the _imageIndex? Because, the code that I provided to you sets image index to the index of the selected item, so it can't be out of range. Anyway, added additional check that _imageIndex is not out of range (if it's between 0 and count of images then it's definitely in range)

Comment: I can't find anywhere where it was increased unfortunately except at mnuOpen_Click where I set it to Zero. Just for clarity, listView1 and _imageIndex both have the same value when the exception triggers so your check won't execute.

To add more detail the exception also says InvalidArgument=Value of '8' is not valid for 'index'.
Other than that just deleting that one line seems to make it work fine as mentioned earlier.